# Cheap solutions to share old laptop screen to Smart TV

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

Hi I have an old laptop that only provide a VGA output connector. I want to use my Samsung Smart TV as its screen so that I can put my laptop next to my TV and forget about opening its lid to look at its sorry 14" screen again. What are my options here?

Something I have tried so far:

1. I used a VGA cable + VGA-DVI adaptor + DVI-HDMI adaptor to connect the HDMI port, no signal.
2. I bought a XXCast dongle and installed its Windows software, I can mirror/extend my desktop to my TV. But this requires me to open up that software before I can start operating from my TV, which is not ideal.

Don't know why the adaptor option didn't work, may be related to analog vs digital signals. So I am thinking something like an external VGA-HDMI convertor.

Also there is something like USB-HDMI connector but I am not sure how it can make my laptop to output screen signal via USB, do I need software installed? And does it utilise my graphic card to allow me to play games?

Comment: Please can you edit this question such that it isn't blatantly asking for shopping advice?  Shopping questions are off-topic ([help]) but this question is salvageable with editing.

Comment: http://www.cellphonecases.com/Hdmi-To-Vga-Cable-2m.html?utm_source=googleshopping&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=productads&gclid=CJTE8f_C98ICFa5zMgodc3YAbw

Answer (score 1):

With that many converts you are probably suffering power loss and that is why it does not work. Get a VGA to HDMI. Only use one adapter. You can get a Belkin VGA to HDMI for about $50 or you can go cheap and pick one up for about $15-$20. If it was me I would go the Belkin one for $50 or a well known brand.